# How to convert blob to zip with pure javascript without any libraries on client side?

Tags: javascript, zip, blob

I'm trying to convert blob to zip file.
In result of actual code I'm getting zip file, but it is in wrong format, so I can't open it.
Does anyone know how to convert blob to zip file in correct format without libraries on client side?

My actual code:

```html
<input type="file" onchange="makeArchive(this.files)" value='files' multiple>
```

```js
function makeArchive(files) {
        const a = document.createElement('a');

        const blob = new Blob([...files], {type: 'application/zip'});
        
        a.href = URL.createObjectURL(blob);
        a.download = `some.zip`;
        a.click();
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

**It is not possible to easily create a ZIP archive using JavaScript without any 3rd-party libraries**.

The function in your example snipped is just concatenating the binary data of the files into one large blob. Specifying a MIME-type of `application/zip` has no effect on the encoding of the files and just tells JavaScript to treat the binary data *like it was a ZIP file*:

```js
// Example data:
const a = new Uint16Array([1337]);
const b = new Uint16Array([42]);

// This just combines the data of a and b into one file:
const stillNotAZip = new Blob([a, b], { type: "application/zip" });

stillNotAZip.arrayBuffer().then(data => console.log(new Uint16Array(data)));
// Will output [1337, 42]
```

If you want to create an actual ZIP file without implementing the format yourself, you will have to resort to using a libraries like [JSZip](https://stuk.github.io/jszip/).